# If I set http.sslVerify to false in git, then will the connection be secure?

Tags: tls, cryptography, firewalls, openssl

If I set "http.sslVerify false"(in .gitconfig file) in git, then will the connection be secure? In between, we are using pfsense firewall and squid+squidgaurd for web-filtering.

Is this a good path to use?

Comment: This question isn't very clear - if might make more sense if you explain what you are attempting to achieve by setting this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is not secure. If git isn't verifying the SSL certificates of the remotes, a MITM attack is pretty simple and straightforward. Anyone could tamper with your code and even build exploits into your software without you even noticing; thats about the worst thing that can happen to a software project.

Comment: As a gateway we are using pfsense firewall with squid with https enable then also connection is insecure?

Comment: Depends on how the firewall is configured. Unless the firewall is itself MITMing HTTPS traffic it will not verify the certificate for you. If it is indeed MITMing HTTPS traffic it still has to be configured to actually verify the certificates. Same goes for squidguard.